# Is there a better way of solving recursive fibonacci in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, fibonacci

I want to return a Fibonacci sequence for a given number; and I want to do so recursively.

Here is my working solution:

```js
function fibonacci(number, previous = 0, current = 0, index = 1) {
    if (index === number) {
        return [current + previous]
    }

    return [(index < 3) ? 1 : current + previous]
    .concat(fibonacci(number, current, (index < 3) ? 1 : current + previous, index + 1))
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(fibonacci(7)))
```

Is there a way to get rid of the conditional (ternary) operators while only using one function?

Comment: recursive:
function fibonacci(num) {
  if (num <= 1) return 1;

  return fibonacci(num - 1) + fibonacci(num - 2);
}

Comment: OP is asking for the sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this. The code is pretty much self explanatory for any that knows fibonacci sequence. I am nesting the recursive calls to the function and when it returns, the last 2 elements are added and appended to the array.

```js
var fibonacci = (num) => {
    if (num <= 1)
        return [1];
    if (num === 2)
        return [1, 1];

    let arr = fibonacci(num-1);
    let p1 = arr[arr.length-1];
    let p2 = arr[arr.length-2];
    return [...arr, p1+p2];
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(fibonacci(7)));
```

Comment: The Fibonacci sequence can start with either 0 or 1. Both are equally valid. Fibonacci himself started the sequence using 1 because you can't start with 0 pairs of rabbits.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do.

```js
const fibs = (a, b, n) => n > 0 ? [a, ...fibs(b, a + b, n - 1)] : [];

const fibonacci = n => fibs(1, 1, n);

console.log(JSON.stringify(fibonacci(7)));
```

You could also use default parameters.

```js
const fibonacci = (n, a = 1, b = 1) =>
    n > 0 ? [a, ...fibonacci(n - 1, b, a + b)] : [];

console.log(JSON.stringify(fibonacci(7)));
```

Personally, I prefer not using default parameters.